# $y^{IV} - y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y^{IV} - y = 0$

I solved this differential equation and got an answer :

$$y = C_1e^x + C_2e^{-x} +C_3\cos x + C_4\sin x .$$

But the book gives different answer:

$$y = C_1\cos2x + C_2\sin2x. $$

Could you please explain me how did they get this?

Comment: Your answer is correct and the book is wrong.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I cant see how my answer and books answer are equivalent

Comment: @Kate They are not.

Comment: Are you sure that the question is about $y^{\text{IV}}$ rather than $y''$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes. There is probably a typo in the book

Comment: @Omnomnomnom if the question was about $y^{''}$ the answer would be $C_1e^x + C_2e^{-x}$. Still it is not what book suggests, isnt it?

Comment: Well there could be two typos so that the question was meant to be $y'' + y = 0$. In any case, something is amiss.

Comment: Who already saw $y^{\text{IV}}$ standing for $y''''$ ? One more typo in a textbook ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE for the printed answer of text-book is

$$ y^{''}+4y =0$$

which may have been misprinted $ y^{IV}+y=0$

Your answer for the ODE as given (or with an alternate prime notation  $ y^{''''}+y=0$), is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i y^{(i)}(t)=0$ is a linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients of order $n$, then multiplying by $e^{\alpha t}$ yields $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i e^{\alpha t} y^{(i)}(t)=0$. Since $e^{\alpha t}>0$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$, we must have that $\alpha$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^n$. In this case the characteristic polynomial is $x^4 - 1$, which has roots $1, -1, i, -i$. Hence the general solution to the ODE is
\begin{align}
y(t) &= C_1 e^{t} + C_2 e^{-t} + C_3 e^{it} + C_4 e^{-it}\\
&= C_1 e^{t} + C_2 e^{-t} + C_3(\cos t + i\sin t) + C_4(\cos t - i\sin t)\\
&= C_1 e^{t} + C_2 e^{-t} + (C_3+C_4)\cos t + (C_3-C_4)i\sin t\\
&= C_1 e^{t} + C_2 e^{-t} C_3'\cos t+ C_4'\sin t.
\end{align}
So you are correct.